# UNIX join not working because one of the files isnt sorted, even though i did sort them

Tags: sorting, unix

I have a bed file with genomic domains in the following format:

- UniProtKB accession, BED line name.
- Chromosome name.
- Annotation start coordinate on the chromosome.
- Annotation end coordinate on the chromosome.
- DNA strand +/- for forward or reverse.
- Annotation description 
   
  A few lines for example: 
  chr1    145926066       145926607       A0A023T787      -       W73-V151; RRM 
  chr8    32595835        32605667        A0A024QY88      +       P37-T128; Ig-like 
  chr8    32727977        32742708        A0A024QY88      +       H178-Q222; EGF-like 
  chr7    101128510       101137439       A0A024QYT5      +       V40-P402; Serpin 
  chr7    101154514       101159187       A0A024QYT6      +       M1-L140; AP complex mu/sigma subunit 
  chr16   28732026        28735223        A0A024QYU9      +       F673-P849; PCI 
  chrX    49172054        49174400        A0A024QYW3      +       F19-Q137; MARVEL

however when i try to sort it, using `sort -k1,1 -t $'\t' -o sorted_domain.bed domain.bed` 
and then try to join it i get: 
`join: sorted_domain.bed:4: is not sorted: chr7  101128510       101137439       A0A024QYT5      +       V40-P402; Serpin`

I saw the similar post that suggested to use `sort -c sorted_domain.bed` and it returned `sort: sorted_domain.bed:4: disorder: chr7       101128510       101137439       A0A024QYT5      +       V40-P402; Serpin`

Comment: If `sort -c` does what you require, why not use that and move on?  You only showed 1 data sample, what do you join it with?  Please profice a [mcve].